# Selenium(Python) alternative to for loop with index

Tags: python, selenium, loops, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

Is there a more efficient way of reading classes with the same name, rather than doing what im doing, i basically go through a code with index, because they all have the same name, is there a better way if selecting elements with the same class name, rather than the way i am doing it

```
Z = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('Class_With_Names'))

for x in range(Z):

x += 1

thisClass = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//ul[@class='same_name']/div[{str(x)}]")
classText = thisClass.find_element_by_class_name("class_with_text")

print(classText.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the find_element**s**_by_xpath? This will return all of the elements with that class name.

Your code looks like it is incrementing after the div though? Are you just looking for information on all of the classes or to loop through the divs?

Comment: well that does work, but when each of those elements have a text, it doesnt print all of the text, gives me some sort of list error

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the *index* you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

To extract and print the texts e.g. *Apple*, *Orange*, etc from all of the `<li class="Fruit">` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.same_name div")])
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='same_name']//div")])
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.same_name div")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='same_name']//div")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)